# Navigation bar some no xcode com swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uinavigationcontroller

Estou fazendo um aplicativo em swift no xcode 7.2.1, estou usando navigation controller nesse aplicativo. criei as segues usando o push, até ai as barras de navegação estavam aparecendo na parte superior.
Mas precisava que uma das ViewControllers não mostrasse essa barra, ai adicionei esse código no viewDidLoad() da ViewController que eu não deveria mostrar a barra.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Tudo funcionou perfeitamente na execução, a barra continua aparecendo em todas as outras menos nessa, mas no Storyboard as barras não aparecem mais de forma nenhuma. sumiu de todas as views. na execução ela funciona da forma esperada, mas no storyborad ela não aparece de forma alguma, nem se eu apagar a view e criar outra. Não sei como fazer para elas aparecesse de novo, e preciso delas para terminar de edita-las. alguém sabe como faze-las aparecem de novo? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou se você não deletou a raiz do NavigationController no storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Você adicionou um navigationController? Pode experimentar fazer Editor->Embeb in -> Navigation Controller para mim fica mais fácil trabalhar desta maneira pois fico com mais versatilidade.

Comment: Sim, fiz esse procedimento, mas depois de um tempo ela não aparece mais no storyboard.

Comment: faz a chamada para as páginas onde não aparece a Navigation da seguinte maneira ` let mapViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as? NomeDaPágina
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: true)`